# What will happen to bottle of cola after 50 years?

Tags: food-chemistry

I'm going to make a time capsule for 25 or 50 years, and I don't know wether it's safe to put food, e.g. bottle of cola there. Will it explode and ruin the capsule? Will it be ok to drink it, if it won't explode?
Also, what about Snickers or a hamburger in a ziploc package with air sucked out of it with vacuum cleaner?

So: will Snickers, Hamburger in a ziploc, Bottle (or can) of Cola, all not opened, go crazy in 25 years? In 50 years? If so, can they go out of their packages and ruin the contents of the time capsule? If not, will it be safe to consume one of them?

Comment: My money is on the bottle of cola making it, the others not so much. I'd stay away from the Snickers and hamburger in the ziploc bag with the air sucked out by using a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: I like your idea, even if none of us will still be around to witness the outcome. Now, hamburgers are known to remain _visually_ unchanged for a few years at least (not that I recommend consuming them afterwards). Cola bottle, on the other hand, is made of plastic, and it may grow brittle over decades.

Comment: Glass bottle of Cola will do fine, I guess. Also, you get some [spare money](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bottle_cap) if the future won't turn out to be so bright.

Comment: Yeah, if you want liquids, use glass bottles.

Comment: Hummmm... glass bottles have a metal cap (steel if I remember correctly). A  time capsule would be in the dark. It is light that degrades plastic the most not time.

Comment: You might want to include some vapor phase corrosion inhibitors in a sealed bag containing any bottle with metal top. BTW, why not freeze-dried food, such as freeze-dried ice cream?

Comment: Maybe you should *purposefully* put in some things you think might not make it, along with a list of items inside, and preferably photos of how they looked prior to burial. Not often are everyday foods and drinks left forgotten for 25 or 50 years. I imagine in most cases we don't actually know what would happen to them. Could be an experiment of sorts! But *definitely* don't consume them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to make a time capsule for 25 or 50 years, and I don't know whether it's safe to put food, e.g. bottle of cola there.

Depends on the food and the way it's packed, but food is not something I'd suggest you pack for such a long period..

> Will it explode and ruin the capsule ?

Food or drink are very unlikely to explode (maybe alcohol would in the wrong circumstances).

But food can be unsafe to eat in quite a short time, depending on the food, preparation and packing and how you store it.  Bacteria could be a problem.

Most food will go bad over a period as long as you're describing without very specific storage (like refrigeration, and even then I'd say most things won't work).

The safest ones would be :

- popcorn (kernels)
- honey (jar of)
- sugar (most forms)
- alcohol (spirits like vodka, whiskey)
- dried beans, dried lentils

I would *not* be planning to eat any of these stored for 25 years myself.  And in general I'd suggest testing the items before trying them after 25 years or more (if you feel you must).

I would *not* expect cans or glass or plastic bottles of soda to be in good shape after anything like 25 years.  The plastic might not survive without degrading.  The can and plastic might react with the liquid over that timescale and the glass would survive but I'd be less optimistic about a sugar laced chemical soup like soda or cola not undergoing some changes.  Hard to say.

If you want more info on this try [this website](http://www.eatbydate.com/).

> Will it be ok to drink it, if it won't explode?

I would not try it.  At best it soda would be flat and possibly not taste the same (chemical changes over that timescale ?) and at worst it could actually be harmful.

Exploding seems very unlikely.

> Also, what about Snickers or a hamburger in a ziploc package with air sucked out of it with vacuum cleaner?

Air isn't the issue.  There are bacteria that will happily live (and increase in numbers) on what's in the food.  Well, it is food, after all.  There are bacteria that will survive refrigeration as well.  Over the timescale you're talking about I'd say it's all bets are off territory.

> So: will Snickers, Hamburger in a ziploc, Bottle (or can) of Cola, all not opened, go crazy in 25 years? In 50 years?

All of those could be dangerous over such a long time period, IMO.  At the very least they'd taste bad and at worst they'd kill you if you consumed them.

> If so, can they go out of their packages and ruin the contents of the time capsule? If not, will it be safe to consume one of them?

Depends on the packaging.  Glass would last indefinitely baring physical force or extreme of hot and cold (which might possibly cause fatigue cracking).  The other wrappers would last pretty well (structurally), but 25 years is *way* past their design intentions.  It would be a dice throw.

Comment: I know! I'll just make two capsules: one with stuff and one with food, and bury them together!